# Is this proof using AM-GM valid?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I was reading about the [AM-GM inequality at brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/applying-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/).

In one of the examples, it proves that:

$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)\ge 4ab  ,  ab\in\mathbb{R^+}$

[image: Here is a picture of the example]

But I thought applying the AM-GM inequality to a term with a constant is invalid since $(a^2+1)$ can be written as diffrent terms like $(a^2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})$ which would result in a diffrent answer.

If im wrong, can someone explain to me where my logic is flaud?

Comment: Why should that be invalid?

Comment: Because the number 1 can be written as different sums, which would give different answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will result in a different answer, but those are inequalities – there is no such thing as one best answer. You will get many different estimates this way, and all of them might be useful in an appropriate situation.

In your case, applying AM-GM to $a^2, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}$ will yield

$$ a^2 + 1 \geqslant \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}} a^{\frac{2}{3}}. $$

This is still true, and it is not always worse (or not always better) than $2a$ bound. The latter one is just more appropriate to the problem you are solving.

Looking at that a little deeper, the issue is: how big do you expect $a$ to be?

In your problem, equality $a^2+1 \geqslant 2a$ holds only if $a=1$, so this value of $a$ is the one we should be paying attention to. If, however, we expect $a$ to be around $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}$, then $2a$ is approximately $\sqrt{2}$, and our strange-looking expression $\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}} a^{\frac{2}{3}}$ turns out to be $\frac{3}{2}$ – so our choice of $a^2, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}$ gave us a better result! (an optimal one, in fact)

This is obviously the effect of AM-GM being optimal when variables are equal to each other. If you try to solve a problem via AM-GM, paying attention to the cases when we have equality is usually worth doing.

One last example when artificially breaking down a constant might help: if we are interested in estimating $\sqrt[n]{x}$, then by using AM-GM for $x$ and $1,1,\ldots,1$ (with $n-1$ ones) we get

$$ \frac{x+n-1}{n} \geqslant \sqrt[n]{x}, $$

which, again, is a good estimate near $x=1$, and it might be hard to obtain without the many-ones trick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if I was to find the smallest value of (a^2+1)(b^2+1). I could not use the constants. How would I solve the question with AM-GM then?

Comment: What do you mean "the smallest value"? That you have some set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that you know that $(a,b) \in U$?

Comment: No. It was a badly formulated question by me. The reason I even created this post was because of this question at brilliant.org: https://brilliant.org/problems/in-the-middle-of-2016/ . On the website, they say you can't use the formula with 2016 since it can be written in multiple ways. And the smallest value of the term will be incorrect. I thought this would apply to the inequality I originally asked about as well. But it appears only to matter when finding the smallest value of an expression. Which I find weird.

Comment: I don't think the reason is that 2016 can be written in multiple ways. It's just that $2016$ is completely independent of $x$, so there's no point in using it.

In desperation, you can also write $2016 = 1 + 1 + \ldots + 1$, and I think it should work, but here it's just overcomplicating things. (But, again, to use AM-GM in proving the right bound, you need to have equal terms.)